# Android List View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was wondering if it was possible to populate the contents of the List View with an xml file that's hosted on the web.. I have looked in quite a few places. Particularly here. But i am guessing that since, it's part of the layout, that the list of strings needs to be available at compile time..

It would be very helpful for me if the list could be populated by a web resource..

maybe applying a SAX parser to populate the strings, within the string class itself? and then notifying the list adapter of changes to the list of strings would work?

Comment: Are you referring to the data displayed in the ListView, or the layout (how it's displayed i.e. the R.layout.something file)?

Comment: the data in the ListView.. For instance, in the HelloListView tutorial, the list of countries needs to be taken from an XML file hosted on the net.. If possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your referring to the data to be displayed, You'll need to pull the information from the web then put it into a ListAdapter then display that (see http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html )

Also this questron may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060299/how-to-show-dynamic-list-view-with-images-using-sax-parser-from-net-in-android

Comment: I think i understand.. Basically the "this" parameter in 

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

needs to be replaced with a class object with the file that does the parsing?

Comment: Unless your setting your listAdapter outside the "extends ListActivity" or "extends Activity" class then "this" will always be "this", if you are setting it from something like a OnItemClickListener (for example if you have a button and pressing it pull the data and populates the list) then use getApplicationContext() in it's place (i.e.  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));  )

Comment: So i'll need to basically define a class object 'myListAdapter' and then put that object inside 'setListAdapter(myListAdapter);' and inside this 'ListAdapter.java' is where i'll need to do the xml parsing work? And this 'myListAdapter.class' should return the contents of the full list or individual elements?